# How to make PsqlDataReader use a larger size for a LongVarChar field type?

Tags: c#, datareader, pervasive-sql

I have a table in my Pervasive.SQL table that is of type `LongVarChar`, which is essentially a blob type field designed for string data.

When I execute a `PsqlDataReader` against this table, the field size the reader reports for the field is 65500.  There is also a flag for `IsLong`, which is rightly `true`.

I would have expected the field size to be either something much larger than 65500, or -1, because I thought I understood that to be the flag for "as long as it needs to be", or some such thing.

Do I have any control over this at a high enough level to do it generically?  As in, without knowing anything about the table I am reading, or the fields it contains?  Some way to tell it to automatically recognize that the field is massive and to thusly set an appropriately large size?

Note that I have manually tested the outcome that I want by retrieving the schema, resetting the field size from 65500 to `Int32.MaxValue` and then loading data from the reader.  With 65500, I would get a constraint exception.  At `Int32.MaxValue`, I do not.

Additional information found in Pervasive's documentation:

> In a single call to SQLGetData, the maximum number of characters
>   returned by Pervasive PSQL for a LONGVARCHAR or LONGVARBINARY columns
>   is 65500. Multiple calls must be made to SQLGetData to retrieve column
>   data over 65500 characters.

That seems to explain why the `PsqlDataReader` is getting the size of 65500.  Likely they make a single call and use the size.  But...still do not know what to do about the impact that that limitation is having on my ability to `DataTable.Load(reader)`.  It does fetch the complete field data, by the way.  I think it is only the schema fetch that is wrong.

Comment: What version of PSQL are you using?  What version of the ADO.NET provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this never got an answer, I'll post the remedy I ended up using:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    if (dc.DataType == typeof(String) && dc.MaxLength == 65500)  //only true for LongVarChar
        dc.MaxLength = Int32.MaxValue;
}
```

This code appears near the end of a method that loads data into a `DataTable`.  Once the table is filled, this loop kicks in and expands the field width for any `LongVarChar` columns, beating the default limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I wrote for someone else with a similar problem some time ago.  It loads a text file into a LongVarChar field then reads it back and writes it to a new file.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Pervasive.Data.SqlClient;

class LoadText
{
    static string fileName = @"loadtext.txt";

    static PsqlConnection conn = null;
    static PsqlCommand cmd = null;

    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string textFile = fileName;
            Console.WriteLine("Loading File: " + textFile);
            conn = new PsqlConnection(@"ServerDSN=DEMODATA");
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new PsqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"create table texttable(textfile varchar(255),textdata longvarchar)";
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = @"insert into texttable values (?,?)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@textfile", PsqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@textdata", PsqlDbType.LongVarChar, 1000000);

            Console.WriteLine("Loading File: " + textFile);

            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(textFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(fs1);
            string textData = "";
            textData = sr1.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine("TextBytes has length {0} bytes.", textData.Length);

            //string textData = GetTextFile(textFile);
            cmd.Parameters["@textfile"].Value = textFile;
            cmd.Parameters["@textdata"].Value = textData;

            cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Loaded {0} into texttable.", fileName);

            cmd.CommandText = "select * from texttable";
            PsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                textFile = @"Output.txt";
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(textFile);
                sw.Write(dr[1].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("TextFile: {0}.\nTextData written to {1}", dr[0].ToString(), textFile);
            }

        }
        catch (PsqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's not the loading of the data that must change, but instead the moment of storage?  I am not certain how to interpret how this can help me.